# Logback tutorial

Tags: documentation, log4j, slf4j, logback

Where can I find a Logback tutorial and/or sample projects? Something similar with this "[Log4j Tutorial](http://www.vaannila.com/log4j/log4j-tutorial/log4j-tutorial.html)" would be nice.

Note: I am aware of the documentation available on the official Logback website

[The Logback Manual](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/index.html)

[Logback documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/documentation.html)

but is there anything else available?

Answer (score 9):

To me, the java sources from the [logback-examples](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/tree/master/logback-examples/) of [the manual](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/index.html) are perfect for this purpose. Not sure you can find better stuff than the genuine samples from the author.

Comment: +1 as anno 2011, the documentation contains a lot of complete configuration examples that are well explained.

Answer (score 5):

You might take a look at the logback demo, [here](http://logback.qos.ch/demo.html).

It will walk you through some of the main logback features.

Hope this helps...